# POWERSHELL script to change SQL Server TCP IPALL port?

Tags: powershell, tcp, ssms

I have found a lot of scripts online that say this can be done but have not yet found one that works ? I would like to be able to change the TCP IPALL port and SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) with a PowerShell script.

I see scripts that say they do this but have not gotten one of them to work... Can someone please share their ideas leads or links to something they feel would work I have been trying to work on this now for over 3 weeks

```
param ( [string]$server_name = $(Read-Host -prompt Server) )
$Machine = new-object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer' $server_name $instance = $Machine.ServerInstances[ 'MSSQLSERVER' ];
$instance.ServerProtocols[ 'Tcp' ].IsEnabled = $true;
$instance.ServerProtocols[ 'Tcp' ].Alter();
$ipAll = $instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].IPAddresses['IPAll'];
$ipAll.IPAddressProperties['TcpPort'].Value = "14330";
$ipAll.IPAddressProperties['TcpDynamicPorts'].Value = "" $instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].Alter();
```

All I get when running this is errors.... I have also tried others:

```
import-module sqlps; $MachineObject = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.WMI.ManagedComputer') "computername"
$instance = $MachineObject.getSmoObject( "ManagedComputer[@Name='computername']/" + "ServerInstance[@Name='instancename']" )
$instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].IPAddresses['IPAll'].IPAddressProperties['TcpPort'].Value = "1433"
$instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].IPAddresses['IPAll'].IPAddressProperties['TcpDynamicPorts'].Value = "" $instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].Alter()
```

Same results nothing but errors when running the code.

The errors I get are pertaining to not finding the database I don't know what they mean but the script can not find the paths to update so it errors out

Comment: In keeping with SO stated methodology, please provide the source code you have tried (as text) and the results.

Comment: ` param (
    [string]$server_name = $(Read-Host -prompt Server)
)
$Machine = new-object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer' $server_name

$instance = $Machine.ServerInstances[ 'MSSQLSERVER' ];

$instance.ServerProtocols[ 'Tcp' ].IsEnabled = $true;
$instance.ServerProtocols[ 'Tcp' ].Alter();

$ipAll = $instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].IPAddresses['IPAll'];
$ipAll.IPAddressProperties['TcpPort'].Value = "14330";
$ipAll.IPAddressProperties['TcpDynamicPorts'].Value = ""
$instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].Alter(); `

Comment: All I get when running this is errors ? I have also tried others ?

Comment: ' import-module sqlps;
$MachineObject = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.WMI.ManagedComputer') "computername"
$instance = $MachineObject.getSmoObject(
   "ManagedComputer[@Name='computername']/" + 
   "ServerInstance[@Name='instancename']"
)

$instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].IPAddresses['IPAll'].IPAddressProperties['TcpPort'].Value = "1433"
$instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].IPAddresses['IPAll'].IPAddressProperties['TcpDynamicPorts'].Value = ""
$instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].Alter() ' same results nothing but errors when running the code ?

Comment: What errors do you get? Please update your post, do not post as images or comments

Comment: Is your sample code exactly what you're using in your live script? You've got what look like syntax errors - e.g. the ```$instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].Alter()``` floating at the end of your second sample that should probably be on its own line., and boilerplate values like ```computername``` and ```instancename``` that don't seem to be parameterised. Could you confirm if these are typos in your question, or if they appear this way in your real code as well, because they could be half of your problem if they do...

Comment: Those names are placeholders for an actual SQL server instance